# Python Module error even though init file kept

Tags: python, batch-file, python-module

[image]

I am not sure what to do here.

The below image shows the heirarchy.

[image]

I tried **init** file in the code.

Kept main.py (not using it) in the parent folder

Comment: Please read the Python documentation pages [Command line and environment](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) with information about the environment variable __PYTHONPATH__ and [Using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) and [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) to get knowledge how Python finds modules (libraries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that "import Data_Upload" looks for that file in the current directory.  In your example, the current directory is `E:\Traffic_Dip_4G`, and that's not where the module is located.  You need to add the parent of your top-level directory to the Python path (`sys.path`) so it can be found.

Something like this, BEFORE you do any other imports:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/../..'))
```

Comment: Thanks, man.. This solved my issue
At the start of the code, I added this.

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'F:/Traffic_Dip_4G/')

Comment: It's good that you solved your problem, but remember that solution will not work if you try to send the script to someone else, who will have a different directory structure.  Hard-coded paths can be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented the absolute path itself like __file__.